# Python return function reasoning

Tags: python

What is the **reason** behind having return after defining a function? Please explain in non coding terms. I am trying to understand why to do return and what it actually does instead of just being told to do it.

Comment: Read [this](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pip2/Functions/Returningavaluefromafunction.html).

Answer (score 0):

`return` just simple makes the function give that thing as the value of something, demo:

```
def f():
    return 'Hello World'
```

And then you do:

```
variable=f()
```

Then now:

```
print(variable)
```

Is gonna be:

```
Hello World
```

OTOH, `print` just does this:

```
def f():
    print('Hello World')
```

Now:

```
f()
```

Is:

```
Hello World
```

But:

```
print(f())
```

Is:

```
Hello World
None
```

And if you do:

```
variable=f()
print(variable.lower())
```

The first one will work with `.lower()` to make it lowercase, but `print` doesn't, instead, does an error.